# How to move all element in array to bottom if?

Tags: javascript

How to move all elements in an array to the bottom if the element of an array(object) not have field date?

```
let records = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2, "date": new Date()}];

return records.sort(function(a: any, b: any) {
      return a.hasOwnProperty('date')
        ? -1
        : b.hasOwnProperty('date')
        ? 1
        : 0;
    });
```

So I need that all elements with the date were sorted and rest others without date placed on the bottom of the list.

Comment: on which parameter is the sorting taking place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check and move the undwanted to bottom by taking a delta of the check.

```js
const
    getISO = d => d instanceof Date
        ? d.toISOString()
        : d;

let records = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2, date: new Date('2020-01-01') }, { id: 3 }, , { id: 2 }, { id: 4, date: new Date }];

records.sort((a, b) => 
    Number('date' in b) - Number('date' in a) ||
    getISO(b.date || '').localeCompare(getISO(a.date || ''))
);

console.log(records);
```

Comment: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts

Comment: Yes it works, but no sorting by date value if date is present

Comment: If one date is greater then another it does not come to top

Comment: you could get either an iso string for sorting or an empty string.

Comment: Yes, but it is important to show freshest row in the top by date

Comment: When I change date in element i does not come on the top of list as freshest element by date.

Comment: just change `a` and `b` for getting an inverse sort order.